# applescript Illustrator scaling based on return dialog

Tags: applescript, adobe-illustrator

I'm working on a script to eliminate repetition.What I have so far will obtain the current size of the art in Illustrator and display the size in inches but I'm having trouble figuring out how to scale the art based on a return dialog. I'm trying to get it to scale the art proportionally to the measurement returned for the width. It will then resize the artboard  based on the new size of the art (this part works). Here's what I have so far

```
tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
activate
tell document 1
    --define Spot1
    set docColorSpace to color space
    if (docColorSpace is CMYK) then
        set SpotColor1 to {cyan:21.0, magenta:0, yellow:100.0, black:0.0}
    else
        set SpotColor1 to {red:206.0, green:219.0, blue:41.0}

    end if

    --color change first
    set (path items whose fill color is not SpotColor1)'s fill color to SpotColor1



    --get current size
    set tempGroup to make new group item with properties {name:"TempGroup"} -- Create a temporary container group
    duplicate every page item to beginning of group item "TempGroup" -- copy instances to it
    set {w, h} to {width, height} of tempGroup -- get properties
    delete tempGroup
    display dialog "Width of Art: " & (w / 72) & return & "Height of Art: " & (h / 72)



    --change to desired size PROBLEM SECTION        
    set ArtWidth to text returned of (display dialog "Please enter Art Width:" default answer "10")

    try
        if (w / 72) is greater than ArtWidth then
            set sizeDifference to (ArtWidth - (w / 72)) as integer
        else
            if (w / 72) is less than ArtWidth then
                set sizeDifference to ((w / 72) - ArtWidth) as integer

            end if
        end if


        set has selected artwork of (every layer of document 1) to true
        set everyPageItem to artItem
        set x1orig to item 1 of activeArt
        set y1orig to item 2 of activeArt
        set x2orig to item 3 of activeArt
        set y2orig to item 4 of activeArt
                    --not sure if activeArt


        --determine new page size (add inch in each direction)
        set x1new to (x1orig - sizeDifference) as real
        set y1new to (y1orig + sizeDifference) as real
        set x2new to (x2orig + sizeDifference) as real
        set y2new to (y2orig - sizeDifference) as real
        --set new art size
        set artItem to {x1new, y1new, x2new, y2new}



        --fit artboard to art 
        set tempGroup to make new group item with properties {name:"TempGroup"} -- Create a temporary container group
        duplicate every page item to beginning of group item "TempGroup" -- copy instances to it
        set {w, h} to {width, height} of tempGroup -- get properties
        set theBounds to visible bounds of tempGroup
        set artboard rectangle of first artboard to theBounds
        delete tempGroup

        -- one inch border      
        tell artboard 1
            --get original page size
            set artPage to artboard rectangle
            set x1orig to item 1 of artPage
            set y1orig to item 2 of artPage
            set x2orig to item 3 of artPage
            set y2orig to item 4 of artPage

            --determine new page size (add inch in each direction)
            set x1new to (x1orig - 72) as real
            set y1new to (y1orig + 72) as real
            set x2new to (x2orig + 72) as real
            set y2new to (y2orig - 72) as real
            --set new page size
            set artboard rectangle to {x1new, y1new, x2new, y2new}

            --print to rip, set path to folder

            --hop out to finder, close & file folders where they go 



        end tell

    end try
end tell
end tell
end
```

I'm feel like I'm overlooking an easier way to do this - any suggestions appreciated

Comment: I've returned this question to the first version before edits because you've taken my answer an applied it to the question. This makes it so that the answer no longer actually answers the question. If you are still having the same problem, please edit the question with more details. If you are having a different problem with the new code, please start a new question.

Comment: My mistake - sorry. I marked the question answered. Thank you for your help

Comment: The script you submitted here does scale the art, it's up to me to figure out the correct way to calculate the difference and translate that to scale percentage (right now its scales the art very tiny)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is taken from a subroutine I use for scaling art to a specific width. Notice that the difference in inches doesn't actually matter. You just need to know the scale between the original size and the new size.

```
set newWidth to text returned of (display dialog "Please enter Art Width:" default answer "10")

tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
    set artWidth to width of tempGroup
    set scalePercentage to (newWidth / artWidth) * 100
    scale tempGroup horizontal scale scalePercentage vertical scale scalePercentage
end tell
```

Comment: I see what you're saying and this seems more efficient then what I was trying to do before. I can't get it to work but have posted what I have without the other parts of the script so I can highlight the problem area. The tempGroup is less than ideal as it causes some art to display incorrectly. Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the script was Illustrator works with points rather than inches so I had to convert the points to inches like so

```
tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
activate
tell document 1

    --get current size
    set tempGroup to make new group item with properties {name:"TempGroup"} -- Create a temporary container group
    duplicate every page item to beginning of group item "TempGroup" -- copy instances to it
    set {w, h} to {width, height} of tempGroup -- get properties
    delete tempGroup
    display dialog "Width of Art: " & (w / 72) & return & "Height of Art: " & (h / 72)

    --resize        
    set newWidth to text returned of (display dialog "Please enter Art Width:" default answer "10")
    set artWidth to width of tempGroup
    set sum to (artWidth / newWidth * 100)
    set scalePercentage to (72 / sum * 10000)

    scale tempGroup horizontal scale scalePercentage vertical scale scalePercentage


end tell
end tell

end
```